# Can i retrieve data from an API located on the same repo as my App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, architecture

I would like to retrieve the data (texts, images, etc) of my app from a separate api instead of retrieving it from local or a json file. Always with the idea of ​​going around the matter one more time and showing how I would make the connections with external APIs, etc. Is it mandatory to save all this app in a separate repo and fully deploy it separately?

Comment: If you want a separate api for data then ofcourse you need to deploy it separately

Answer (score 1):

There is no definite answer for that, it depends on your use-case, and there are legit arguments for both cases. If the external API is an independent component which serves more applications and has no special relation to the `app` you're talking about - makes sense to put it in a different repository, it will improve testability and deployability. On the other hand - if there is a strong relation between the external API and the `app`, and a change in any of them requires a change in the other one - putting them in the same repository will reduce the number of deployments (which is a good thing).
Bottom line - it depends on the use-case and there is a trade-off.